# What is causing this Segmentation Fault: 11?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Okay, so this is effectively the first C++ I have ever written. Consequently, my attempts to research this Segmentation Fault error have failed to yield a useful response that I can understand. Most suggestions say that I'm exceeding the heap memory, but I don't see how I could be in this code.  Maybe I'm trying to reference something that I can't reference?

Can someone please take a look at this code and possibly tell me what is causing this error?  The code compiles fine, it just throws this error when it runs.  I have tried commenting out all the code involving vectors, and that didn't solve the problem.  I'm guessing it's something stupid that I'm missing or just a concept about C++ that I don't understand.  Either way, some insight would be much appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 15;



//---------------------------------User----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//User Interface Definition
class User 
{
public:
    User(string nameValue);
    string getName();
    string getWall();
    string getHome();
private:
    string name;
};
//User Implementation Definition
User::User(string nameValue) : name(nameValue)
{
}
string User::getName() 
{
    return name;
}

//---------------------------------Group----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Group Interface Definition
class Group 
{
public:
    Group(string nameValue);
    string getName();
    void addMember(User newMember);
private:
    string name;
    vector<User> members;
};
//Group Implementation
Group::Group(string nameValue) : name(nameValue)
{
}
string Group::getName()
{
    return name;
}
void Group::addMember(User newMember)
{
    members.push_back(newMember);
}

//---------------------------------MessageBuffer----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//MessgeBuffer Interface Declaration
class MessageBuffer 
{
public:
    MessageBuffer();
    void insert(string user, string recipient, string message);
    string readByGroup(string groupName);
    string readByUser(string userName);
    string readPublic();
private:
    string buffer;
};
//MessageBuffer Implementation
MessageBuffer::MessageBuffer() : buffer("")
{
}
void MessageBuffer::insert(string user, string recipient, string message) 
{
    buffer = "|<" + user + "::" + recipient + ">|" + message + buffer;
}
string MessageBuffer::readByGroup(string groupName) 
{
    return "Something";
}
string MessageBuffer::readByUser(string userName)
{
    return "Something";
}
string MessageBuffer::readPublic()
{
    return "Something";
}

//---------------------------------System-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//System Interface Definition
class System 
{
public:
    System();
    void start();
private:
    bool running;
    User currentUser;
    MessageBuffer messageBuffer;
    vector<User> users;
    vector<Group> groups;
};
//System Implementation Definition
System::System() : running(false), currentUser(0)
{
}

void System::start() 
{
    running = true;
    string userSelection;

    cout << "===========================================================" << endl;
    cout << "|\t  Welcome to the Auburn Messaging System! \t  |" << endl;
    cout << "===========================================================" << endl;
    while (running) {
        cout << "1) Create a new user\n";
        cout << "2) Broadcast a message\n";
        cout << "3) Multicast a message\n";
        cout << "4) Unicast a message\n";
        cout << "5) Display Wall page\n";
        cout << "6) Display Home page\n";
        cout << "7) Create a new group\n";
        cout << "8) Join a group\n";
        cout << "9) Switch to a different user\n";
        cout << "10) Quit Auburn Messaging System\n";
        cin >> userSelection;
        if (userSelection == "1")
        {
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    cout << "Part 1";
    System system1;
    cout << "Part 2";
    system1.start();
    cout << "Part 3";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: That probably should've been my first step, but honestly I've just been writing in Sublime and compiling in the terminal. Probably should figure out how to use xCode for this.

Comment: Or learn to use GDB.

Comment: I think you could easily find the problem by commenting out the declaration of `system1`.  This program is simple enough that debugging it could have been a very small process-of-elimination.  That is assuming the crash occurs during the *construction* of `currentUser` -- rather than sometime later.

Comment: @nobar In that sense, I did debug it.  I tried commenting out the declaration of system1, among other things, and it still threw the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `System` constructor, `currentUser(0)` is attempting to initialise a the first parameter of the `User` constructor (a `string`) with a literal zero which will be interpreted as a null char pointer.

The `std::string` constructor (look for `basic_string<char>` in the debugger) which constructs a string from a char* will be called with a null pointer, which it will dereference and invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: That was the problem.  I thought 0 could be used as the C++ equivalent to null in Java.

Comment: Now that you know where the error is (and what it is) use a debugger to observe what the state of the program is at the point it fails.

Comment: @ordanj You sort of have it backwards, in C and C++ NULL is a macro for 0, whereas in Java it is a unique value.  C++11 adds a `nullptr_t`, which is more like the Java null value but will still cause a segfault.

Comment: @ordanj Since C++11 you should use `nullptr` whenever you mean null pointer.

Comment: 0 *is* a null pointer -- which is why this unfortunately compiles.

Comment: If you want to initialize a std::string to an empty string, use an empty string: `""`. You do not want it to be null. Only pointers can be null. (Mythagel, your answer should explain more clearly that the std::string constructor that takes a char pointer is the one that gets called, and that this immediately proceeds to try and dereference a null pointer.)

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, that makes sense.  But, I was trying to initialize a new object of the User class, not an empty string.

Comment: @ordanj But the `0` ultimately gets used to initialize a string. C++ is quite complicated. It may be worth starting out with smaller, simpler code samples first.

Comment: @CodyGray clarified wrt. `std::string` constructor given later comments from @ordanj regarding confusion with `User` ctor.